# Persisting form data in Formik across tab switches and navigations: How to do it?

Tags: reactjs, formik-material-ui

My question is divided into two parts as I want to handle both cases.

1. I need to find a way to persist form data, after it is submitted and moved to a different tab in the same page.
2. After filling the form the user gets redirected to another page and when he/she hits a 'back' button gets redirected to this form page and the data they entered should be present.

```
 <Formik
                initialValues={addprojValues}
               
                validationSchema={Yup.object({
                    projectName:Yup.string().required("project Name Required").
                    customerId:Yup.string(),
                    companyName:Yup.string().required
                    email: Yup.string().matches(regexEmailValidation, "Domain Name Missing").required("Email Required"),
                    shortName:Yup.string().required("Short Name Required")
                    requirement:Yup.string().required("Requirement Required"),
                    timeLine:Yup.string().required("Timeline Required").max(3,"Number Of Days Exceeded"),
                    projectStartDate:Yup.date().required("Project StartDate Required"),
                    projectBudget:Yup.string().required("Project Budget Required"),
                })}
                onSubmit={(values)=>{
                   
                    axios.post(createProject,values).then((res)=>{
                        
                        
                       
               
                        
                    }).catch(err=>{return err})
                }}
                 >
                    {
                    formik =>
                <Form autoComplete="off" onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit} id="form" >
                    <div className={styles.addProjectFormData}>
                        <div className={styles.formFeildsColumn1}>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Project Name" name="projectName" value={formik.values.projectName} onChange={formik.handleChange}/>
                            <ErrorMessage name="projectName" render={msg => <div style={errMsg}>{msg}</div>} />
                            <Autocomplete freeSolo
                            disablePortal
                            onInputChange={(e)=>getClientsNames(e.target.value)}
                            className={styles.autoCompleteClientName}
                   
                                
                                onChange={(event,value)=>formik.values.customerId=value.id}
                                options={clientNames}
                                getOptionLabel={option=>option?.name}
                                renderInput={(params) => (
                                <TextField
                                name="customerId"
                                value={formik.values.customerId}
                                placeholder="Client Name" 
                               
                                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                    {...params}
                                    InputProps={{
              
                                        ...params.InputProps,
                                     
                                        type: 'search',
                                        style:{color:"white"},
                                   }}
                                />
                                )}
                            >
                            </Autocomplete>
                            <ErrorMessage name="customerId" render={msg => <div style={errMsg}>{msg}</div>} />

            
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Company Name" name="companyName" value={formik.values.companyName} onChange={formik.handleChange}/>
                            <ErrorMessage name="companyName" render={msg => <div style={errMsg}>{msg}</div>} />

                            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" value={formik.values.email} onChange={formik.handleChange} />
                            <ErrorMessage name="email" render={msg => <div style={errMsg}>{msg}</div>} />

                            <input type="text" placeholder="Short Name" name="shortName" value={formik.values.shortName} onChange={formik.handleChange} />
                            <span style={{display:"flex",alignItems:"center"}}>
                            <p>This Name is used for invoices and estimates</p>
                            <img src="../../../assets/infoImg.svg"/>
                            </span>
                            <ErrorMessage name="shortName" render={msg => <div style={errMsg}>{msg}</div>} />
                            

                            {projectCreation && <Select
                            className={styles.projectTypeDropdown}
                            name="projectType.type"
                            value={formik.values.projectType.type}
                            onChange={formik.handleChange}
                            autoWidth
                            displayEmpty
                            renderValue={(selected) => {
                                if (selected.length === 0) {
                                return <p>Project Type</p>;
                                }
                                return selected;
                                }}
                            inputProps={{ "aria-label": "Without label" }}
                            >
                                {projectType?.map((item)=>(
                                    <MenuItem value={item.type} onClick={()=>formik.values.projectType.id=item.id} >{item.type}</MenuItem>
                                ))}
                            </Select>}
                            <textarea rows={8} placeholder="Requirement" name="requirement" value={formik.values.requirement} onChange={formik.handleChange} />
                            <ErrorMessage name="requirement" render={msg => <div style={errMsg}>{msg}</div>} />

                            
                        </div>
                        <div  className={styles.formFeildsColumn2}>
                            <div className={styles.ProjectAsset}>
                                <p>Project Budget</p>
                                <input type="text" name="projectBudget" value={formik.values.projectBudget} onChange={formik.handleChange} className={styles.projectBudgetValue} />
                            </div>
                            <ErrorMessage name="projectBudget" render={msg => <div style={errMsg}>{msg}</div>} />

                       

                        </div>

                      
                    </div>
               
                    <button type="submit" className={styles.createProjectFormBtn} >create</button>
                </Form>
                }
            
                </Formik>
```

I have tried using setFieldvalue to the form and it works only in case1 and not in the second case.